# How to use ReaderWriterOBJ in OpenSeneGraph

Tags: openscenegraph

Can anyone explain to me how to use ReaderWriterOBJ in OpenSceneGraph? I want to load an obj file along with the mtl file. I have already built the solution for readerWriterObj code and created a dll file.

Answer (score 0):

The ReaderWriter's are just file loaders.  You have to use them in context of an application, like osgviewer, one of the examples included in OSG.  If you've gone through the process of building OSG, you might have already built osgviewer, which will use the appropriate DLL's to load files.

eg

```
osgviewer FILE.obj
```

will open FILE.obj, with its associated material file[s].